# Domain Name is Redirecting to Some Site With Sponsored Links

Tags: dns, domain-name

When I enter in domain name in the address bar and try to visit my site - 
I am redirected to some web page that has listed a bunch of some sponsored links.
I registered my domain name at domainsite.com.
Also, what's even more stranege, after a while when I refresh a page couple of times I am redirected to my web page.
What could be the cause of this?
Can anyone please help me solve this?
(also sometimes when I just put www. before the address - the page is reached. But this doesn't happen everytime I do it)

My site: providenca.net

The "page" to which I am redirected looks like this: http://i48.tinypic.com/2unyby8.png

Comment: Can you please give us the domain name you have registered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what is wrong. Ask domainsite.com if they know the cause. Make sure to try it on another computer to see if the problem persists. If it is located to only your computer, I have to suspect a IP changer virus.

Comment: My site: providenca.net
The "page" to which I am redirected looks like this: http://i48.tinypic.com/2unyby8.png

Comment: Every time I look on, All I see is the cake website in croatian...
Looks delicious!

Comment: thanks :) Than the problem is "hopefully" with my laptop

Comment: Yea. Try it with a different computer! Have fun =)

Comment: can you please help me how to solve the problem? It's really annoying when I can't access my own web page
:)

Comment: Ok. Now I see it... I think it is your domainsite.com doing this...

Comment: So you got the same thing? Or?
What would you suggest me to do?

Comment: Ask domainsite.com what the problem is. If they don't fix it, move hosts.